# How to have Asynchronous call in each loop for FadeIn and Fadeout

Tags: jquery

How to have Asynchronous call in each loop for FadeIn and Fadeout?

I want to fadein and then fadeout one li and then go to the next li; but apparently each loop is making it synchronous! How can I handle this issue?

```
$("#intro li").hide();


var $li = $("#intro li");

$li.each(function(){
    $(this).fadeIn(2000,function(){
     $(this).fadeOut(2000);

    });
})
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/web_developer_888/AGa2m/2/)

I figured out my problem:

[Solved Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AGa2m/5/)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a recursion,

```
$("#intro li").hide();

var $li = $("#intro li");

animateLi($li.first());

function animateLi(li){
  if(!li.length){ return }

  li.fadeIn(2000,function(){
     li.fadeOut(2000,function(){ animateLi(li.next('li')) });
  });
}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AGa2m/3/)

Comment: Thats a good approach but I guess there should be a way to make the for each loop Asynchronous as well!

Comment: @Rajaprabhu but it stopped after final li,OP need previous li should be in DOM

Comment: @SridharR oh.. i see.. then we call it by using the first li inside that breaking if statement. :)